# Durable function activity autogenerated code can't resolve return type

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, azure-durable-functions

Having trouble wrapping my head what's going on with this autogenerated code. I have a durable function I'm upgrading from .netcore3.1 to .net6. Two of my activity functions were returning `Task<JObject>` which was causing a reference error to JObject in the autogenerated code so I converted them to POCOs per a recommendation. When I try to build it's still complaining that the autogenerated code can't resolve my POCO. I'd like to know what is creating this autogenerated code and how to resolve the reference issue.

Activity:

```
  [Function(nameof(GetChangeAsync))]
  public ChangeRequest GetChangeAsync([ActivityTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context)
  {
      var change = context.GetInput<ChangeRequest>();
      var changeRequestJson = _client.GetAsync<ChangeRequest>($"/change-requests/{WebUtility.UrlEncode(change.Id)}?api-version=2018-06-01", change.SubscriptionKey, sandbox: change.IsSandbox);
      return changeRequestJson.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
  }
```

*Note: Even though the method has Async in the name I removed the async and await keywords so that it was only returning a ChangeRequest POCO as opposed to a `Task<ChangeRequest>`.

My ChangeRequest exists in the same namespace and file system folder, is composed of only members from System and has no inheritance. It is public, as are all members:

```
namespace xxx.Itsm.ChangeRequests;

public class ChangeRequest
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Class { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Coordinator { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Impact { get; set; }
    public string Urgency { get; set; }
    public string Service { get; set; }
    public string OperationalCategory { get; set; }
    public string Reason { get; set; }
    public string Justification { get; set; }
    public string SubscriptionKey { get; set; }
    public bool Resolved { get; set; } = false;
    public bool IsSandbox { get; set; } = false;
    public bool IsContinueAsNew { get; set; } = false;
    public string TrackingId { get; set; }
}
```

The autogenerated code looks like this:

```
namespace Microsoft.DurableTask
{
    public static class GeneratedDurableTaskExtensions
    {
        public static Task<ChangeRequest> CallGetChangeAsyncAsync(this TaskOrchestrationContext ctx, TaskOrchestrationContext context, TaskOptions? options = null)
        {
            return ctx.CallActivityAsync<ChangeRequest>("GetChangeAsync", context, options);
        }
...
```

and is throwing the following error:
CS0246    The type or namespace name 'ChangeRequest' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a bug in the durable functions isolated library which is currently in prerelease: https://github.com/microsoft/durabletask-dotnet/issues/35